# How to click radio button in table for handle multiple records in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am creating a table of class attendance module in which teacher clicks on a radio buttons in front of student's name to mark that if he/she is present,absent or on leave and when we submit the rows are saved in MySQL database and jsp.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Each student should have a group of radio buttons with same name different from other students

```
     <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
      //your code   
<td>
            <input type="radio" name="${student.id}" value="present " disabled="true"/> present  
            <input type="radio" name="${student.id}" value="absent" disabled="true"/> absent 
            <input type="radio" name="${student.id}" value="on leave" disabled="true"/> on leave
 </td>          
    //your code 

            </c:forEach>
```

After that you get data with servlet using a loop on  student id

```
for(int i=0 ; i < student.number ; i++)
{
       String id= String.valueOf(i);
       String selected = request.getParameter(id);
//call a method to save data to database            
}
```